# unity5.3.5f1 export to Xcode, build failure: Undefined symbols for arm64. "_DeviceInfoGetDeviceIMSI"

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, build

The problem happens when I export my unity project as Xcode project.
(unity5.3.5f1 personal edition, Xcode 7.2)

it tells that I missed some symbol links,

but **I don't not know where to find this weird errors**.

most of them seems to relate with device info.

here is the snapshot:
[xcode build failure info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMRoH.png)

here is my unity player settings:
[unity player settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGuE3.png)

Comment: Have you added any plugin in your project??
If yes then remove it and try to build.

Answer (score 0):

It seems no info on this issue, perhaps it's caused by thirdparty plugins you used. Good luck!